# How can I unit test meteor package?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

I am using meteor + mongodb + react.
`meteor add meteortesting:mocha`

The .test files in imports/ui... were run but my tests on packages were not recognized.

Do u know how can I run the tests on packages? The meteor documentation is not updated. They use `practicalmeteor:mocha` but it is deprecated now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused are you after testing a meteor package or your meteor application? Either way, I'd recommend [meteortesting:mocha](https://github.com/meteortesting/meteor-mocha). It's even used in [meteor-roles](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-roles/blob/master/package.js#L41).